# Can't get ODA to work via UpdateSite

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I wanted to install the OpenNTF Domino API (first Version 2.0.0, then 3.0.0) on my Domino development server (and into the Designer client).

Everything seems perfect, Domino installs new OSGi features after restart.

The first thing I noticed, was: The Designer wont compile anything when using Classes from package org.openntf.domino. "Cannot be resolved".

Ok - so then I checked Application -> Application Management in DDE but it seemed ok. The package is listed there.

After having no further idea than copying the right jar into jvm/lib/ext, the Designer finally compiled my Xots Tasklet Class.

A quickly built XPage with a button to execute my Tasklet was set up. Clicked the button. And Trace Log replied with:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openntf.domino.xots.Xots

But if I check the server's OSGi status

> tell http osgi ss org.openntf.domino

also looks great:

`30.08.2016 15:48:41 11 RESOLVED org.openntf.domino.source_3.0.0.201608021035
30.08.2016 15:48:41 14 ACTIVE      org.openntf.domino_3.0.0.201608021035
30.08.2016 15:48:41 19 RESOLVED    org.openntf.domino.rest.source_3.0.0.201608021035
30.08.2016 15:48:41   21 ACTIVE      org.openntf.domino.xsp_3.0.0.201608021035
30.08.2016 15:48:41   25 RESOLVED    org.openntf.domino.xsp.source_3.0.0.201608021035
30.08.2016 15:48:41   33 <<LAZY>>    org.openntf.domino.rest_3.0.0.201608021035`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can I check which versions of Domino Designer and Domino are you using? Because ODA is extending the core Domino APIs, it only works with 9.0.1. I notice I haven't clarified that, though the fact it compiled when in jvm\lib\ext suggests that's not the problem.

Comment: Release 9.0.1 
Revision 20131022.0932

Comment: IBM Domino (r) Server (64 Bit) (Release 9.0.1 for Windows/64)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth trying `tell http osgi diag org.openntf.domino`. This identifies any dependency issues. ODA 3.0.0 requires ExtLib 17 (there were some amendments to DAS which we needed).

If you've used earlier versions, ODA could be installed in the jvm\lib\ext folder. We've changed that and it shouldn't be. There were also problems because of reorganisation of the packages to include Maven. I can't remember which version this affected, it may have been 2.0. It needed you to uninstall, then reinstall in order to clean up Domino Designer correctly.

When HTTP task starts, it should write a message to the console "[ODA::Xots] Starting XPages OSGi Tasklet Service with 10 core threads."

If you have the full stack trace, that may help confirm it's trying to use the correct version.

Comment: tell http osgi diag org.openntf.domino:
`[2650:0002-3560] 30.08.2016 17:34:50   initial@osginsf:UpdateSiteSBK.nsf/AFA836B4B30500FEC125801F004AD1CA/org.openntf.domino_3.0.0.201608021035.jar [36]
[2650:0002-3560] 30.08.2016 17:34:50     No unresolved constraints.`
 - 
I did not use earlier versions installed via lib/ext. - The message "[ODA::Xots] Starting XPages OSGi Tasklet Service with 10 core threads" also comes up :/

Comment: What kind of stacktrace do you mean? The NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: Yes. If it's being logged internally, it will be logged to an org.openntf.0.0.log file in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT on the server (if running from a browser) or on the Notes Client (if running from XPiNC)

Comment: Checked these log files. Nothing in it - 0KB.

Comment: I doubt that this will help you, but here's some stack trace that i found:
[http://pastebin.com/pxW1kmnB](http://pastebin.com/pxW1kmnB)

Comment: This is a strange one. What happens if you run `tell http osgi packages org.openntf.domino.xots` on the server console? I'd expect that it will list the org.openntf.domino plugin as a source, which would keep us at square one, but perhaps we'll get lucky and it'll display nothing or an error, indicating some setup problem.

Comment: I fear we're not:
[2650:0002-3560] 01.09.2016 14:03:21   org.openntf.domino.xots; version="0.0.0"<initial@osginsf:UpdateSiteSBK.nsf/AFA836B4B30500FEC125801F004AD1CA/org.openntf.domino_3.0.0.201608021035.jar [36]>[2650:0002-3560] 01.09.2016 14:03:21     initial@osginsf:UpdateSiteSBK.nsf/1E572D05F92970E6C125801F004AD220/org.openntf.domino.rest_3.0.0.201608021035.jar [21] imports

[2650:0002-3560] 01.09.2016 14:03:21     initial@osginsf:UpdateSiteSBK.nsf/C04861EAB370AD0EC125801F004AD1F5/org.openntf.domino.xsp_3.0.0.201608021035.jar [23] imports

Comment: The DDE issues (not compiling, putting it in jvm\lib\ext) looks strange. Maybe something has gone wrong with compilation as a result. I'd recommend removing it from jvm\lib\ext, uninstalling every reference via Application Management, then clean installing. Then try editing and saving the Xots task again - this will check compiling is working, as well as cleaning the Java class files. Because of the various versions, possibly there's a problem with compiling, though we've never changed the package names, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok did this: Removed OpenNTF Domino API from Application Management, restarted DDE (still no errors, because of jar still in jvm/lib/ext), closed DDE, removed jar vom jvm/lib/ext, restarted DDE (compile errors with Xots Tasklet). DDE -> File -> Application -> Install -> search for new features ... installed ODA 3.0.0. Restarted DDE, still compile errors with Xots. Edited Xots Tasklet Class file and saved - still the same.